# How can I set the encoding of a httpExchange response?

Tags: java, encoding

I'm trying to modify some server code which uses an `httpExchange`object to handle the server's response to the client.

My issue is that for responses containing characters not supported by iso-8859-1, such as Chinese characters, I get something like '????' in place of the characters. I'd like to set the encoding of the response to utf-8, but have thus far been unsuccessful in doing so.

I tried adding this line:

```
httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().put("charset", Arrays.asList("UTF-8"));
```

This successfully puts a "charset" header in the response, but I still can't send the characters I want in the response.

How do I set the encoding of the response to allow for these characters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Content-Type` header to specify encoding.

```
String encoding = "UTF-8";

httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=" + encoding);

Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpExchange.getResponseBody(), encoding));
out.write(something);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing that should be `Content-Type`, as in your example, and not `Content-Length`?